# msxml3 error 80090326 in accessing secure URL

Tags: vbscript

I created the following code:

```
  URL = "https://github.com/index.html"
  Set xHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  xHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
  xHttp.setOption 2, 13056
  xHttp.Send()
```

Executing 'xHttp.Send', I get an msxml3 error 0x80090326, "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted".

For other secure URLs the above code works. Not for this one! However, the open source utility 'wget' can access this URL uisng the '--no-check-certificate' switch. Also, web browsers can access this URL. What is needed in VBScript to be able to succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,Save2File
URL = "https://github.com/index.html"
Save2File = "index_github.txt"
Call GetData(URL,Save2File)
 '**********************************************************************************************
 Sub GetData(URL,Save2File)
Dim File,BS,ws
On Error Resume Next
 Set File = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET",URL, False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile Save2File, 2
 End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```